# How to call webservice with self signed certificate from AWS API gateway?

Tags: web-services, aws-api-gateway

My client has an already developed (and frozen) web service which is being secured with self signed certificate. I have configured AWS API gateway to get rid of CORS issue. When I try to call any endpoint of the web service via AWS API gateway, I find HTTP 500 Internal Server error. Until the client web service is made secured with self signed certificate, HTTP based endpoints were accessible via AWS API gateway.

What are ways to still call the web service endpoints?

Comment: Is this an HTTP proxy integration, or a Lambda integration, where the Lambda function is making the request to the web service?

Comment: HTTP proxy integration is done

Answer (score 3):

API Gateway will fail on self signed certificates for http(s) backend integrations.
If you use the test functionality on the API GW you will see a error in the logs that it gives on the right about either a SSL Engine Problem or Bad Certificate.

If your backend is already in AWS and fronted by a load balancer you can think of using free certificates from `ACM`.

Or you can consider using a `NLB` that the API gateway can talk to, using the `NLB` you can have your backend apis' in a VPC and have no public access and still have API GW talk to them.

Edit: For some reason I am not able to link correctly. Here are some links on ACM and NLB.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html

Comment: Yes, I employed VPC_LINK type of integration with NLB.

Comment: I seem to be hitting this issue but in my case I'm trying to link APIGateway with the AWS IoT Data ingestion endpoint.

So trying to link AWS API Gateway with their own AWS IoT Service doesn't work because they seem to use their own CA root which API Gateway is not aware of :-(